# What am I doing that makes ReactJS not performant here?

Tags: javascript, performance, reactjs, rendering

I had an earlier site at https://Pragmatometer.com with main JSX file I created at https://Pragmatometer.com/public/javascripts/site.jsx.

It was not performant, partly because I had overestimated how fast the synthetic DOM was. I went through and did what I thought would be overkill for a performant DOM: set everything that repeats at one repetition per second, and in addition re-render() for all keyboard and some mouse events.

However, things are still responding very sluggishly, as in more than a second delay between clicking on an input[type="text"] and typing, and anything to show up in the input (if something does show up).

It looks like I've done something that has ReactJS really bogged. This is incidentally after followup on another question where I was creating a fresh <Pragmatometer /> per render: now one is created and stored.

What am I doing that is giving ReactJS performance issues?

Comment: Please edit your question to include all of the relevant code. Links to code on other sites may stop working, which makes answers useless for future visitors.

Comment: @Jordan, after SO said "This post is too long", I posted to https://jsfiddle.net/qdejh9sL/ to attempt longevity. The critical parts I would point to are the setTimeout() / setInterval(), and the e.g. keypress methods that trigger a render (and do not preventDefault()).

Comment: That's a lot of code. It sounds like you have some code that's running a lot more than you think it is. It could be that something is continuously triggering re-rendering, or you're creating many duplicate `setInterval`s without clearing old ones. You should use the CPU profiler in Developer Tools to figure out where the hot spot is.

Comment: Incidentally, this is a big antipattern: `this.state.entry_being_added.days_frequency = days;` *Never* set values on `this.state` directly. You *must* use `this.setState` to update your component's state. See the big red note under `setState` in the docs: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html

Comment: Also, your use of jQuery is suspect. I won't say there's never any reason to use jQuery and React together, but you absolutely shouldn't use jQuery to update the DOM like you're doing on lines like these: `jQuery('#month_occurrence').val('-1');` or `jQuery('#Calendar').css('width', window_width * .46);` Update your React components' state or pass them new props and let React re-render them with the attributes you want. Don't try to create a hybrid jQuery/React view layer. That way lies sadness and pain.

Comment: Finally, make smaller components. Each component should render no more than a few elements (with the obvious exception for collections—think complexity). If your `render` method (and any `renderFoos` helpers it calls) doesn't fit on one screen in your editor, you have a big problem that's going to make it much harder to debug problems like the one you're having now. With many small components it's easy to swap out individual pieces to narrow down the problem.

Comment: @Jordan, ``jQuery('#Calendar').css('width', window_width * 46)`` was there because I want dimensions manually calculated, in a way not easily done with CSS (could be done with tables), initially and recalculated on window resize. If I want to have a top area of fixed height and slice up the area below into quarters with gutters, and recalculate on window resize, what approach would you recommend? CSS used to emulate tables? Thanks,

Comment: You can accomplish the same thing by setting the `style` prop in React. `<div style={{ width: window_width * 46 }}>` or whathaveyou. Read the docs on [Inline Styles](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/inline-styles.html).

Comment: Although if you're displaying data in tabular format (like a calendar) you'll probably save yourself a lot of trouble by just using `<table>`.

Comment: How should I be populating what with jQuery is obtained by jQuery(element).width(), e.g. jQuery(window).width()?